# Calling references in incomplete html files for AJAX inclusion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently working with AJAX / Ajaxify to build a client's website. However, when I call a file to replace the content of the main div, I notice that references and non-elemental code don't work properly. For example, if I replace the div with the content from a .html file that only says

```
<h2>Hello there</h2>
```

It appears just fine. However, if I call for a file with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="something.css">
<h2> Hello there </h2>
```

the h2 appears like normal, but the other code appears as text as well. What is going on here?

Comment: Just tried this, unfortunately it continues to do the same, even when setting dataType or contentType.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could share your code.

Comment: `the other code appears as text as well` by any chance are you using jQuery's `text` function instead of `html`?

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because I realised that I was suggesting something wrong.